# Is it possible to change an associated value within an enum?

Tags: swift

I'm playing around with Swift enums and wondering if there is a way to change the assoicated value of an enum such as the code below attempts but fails.

```
enum myEnum {
    case SomeCase(Int?)

    mutating func someFunc() {
        switch self {
        case .SomeCase(let a):
            if a != nil {
                // a = 5 can't do this of course as assigning to let
                var temp = a!; // but this generates a warning
                temp = 5;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If this isn't currently possible, will it be when mutating enums come to XCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rob Napier's answer is fine but I have a different understanding of your question. I would have written something like this instead:

```
enum MyEnum {

    case SomeCase(Int?)

    mutating func someFunc() {
        switch self {
        case .SomeCase(.Some(_)): 
            self = .SomeCase(5)
        default: 
        // or case .SomeCase(.None): if you prefer
            break
        }
    }

}
```

With this code, the `enum` is mutated with `someFunc` if and only if its associated value is not `nil`. Thus, I have the following results while testing in a Playground (results appear as comments):

```
var x = MyEnum.SomeCase(nil)

switch x {
case .SomeCase(.Some(let a)):
    println(a)
default:
    println("Associated value is nil") // Will print "Associated value is nil"
}

x = MyEnum.SomeCase(20)
x.someFunc()

switch x {
case .SomeCase(.Some(let a)):
    println(a) // Will print 5
default:
    println("Associated value is nil")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The whole enum is a single value, so you have to replace it entirely, not field by field. But you can certainly do that by replacing `self`.

```
enum MyEnum {
    case SomeCase(Int?)

    mutating func someFunc() {
        switch self {
        case .SomeCase(_):
            self = .SomeCase(5)
        }
    }
}

// You have to use `var` here of course or you can't mutate it.
var x = MyEnum.SomeCase(1) // .SomeCase(Optional(1))
x.someFunc() // .SomeCase(Optional(5))
```

Comment: Thanks. P.S. I would love to see a book called "iOS 9 Swift Programming. Pushing The Limits". Any chance that would happen ? ;-)

Comment: I'm currently sticking to short-form writing, mostly blogging.