# How to write mutating function for enum in Swift

Tags: swift, enums

I want to write mutating function like the following. But this code cannot be compiled because x and y are immutable and copied value. I want to get the reference of x and y. How to get the reference of variables wrapped by enum?

```swift
enum Fruit {
    case apple(Int)
    case banana(Int, Int, Int)

    mutating func increment() {
        switch self {
        case let .apple(x):
            x += 1
        case let .banana(x, y, z):
            x += 1
        }
    }
}

var a = Fruit.banana(100, 200, 300)
a.increment()
```

I know the following code can do the same thing. But I think this solution is redundant because we have to write each variable twice.

```swift
enum Fruit {
    case apple(Int)
    case banana(Int, Int, Int)

    mutating func increment() {
        switch self {
        case let .apple(x):
            self = .apple(x + 1)
        case let .banana(x, y, z):
            self = .banana(x + 1, y, z)
        }
    }
}

var a = Fruit.banana(100, 200, 300)
a.increment()
```

Comment: Your second code  is exactly how it is done. Compare [Is it possible to change an associated value within an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054931/is-it-possible-to-change-an-associated-value-within-an-enum).

Comment: "But I think this solution will be redundant in more complex cases." What do you mean by "more complex cases"? Do you mean enums with many more cases?

Comment: When enum has a lot of variables a, b, c, d, ...., we have to write each variables twice as we can see this example. I think this is redundant, but it's not hard to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `self = .apple(x)` will do the trick. It is customary, but you already knew this.

```swift
enum Fruit {
    case apple(Int)
    case banana(Int, Int, Int)

    mutating func increment() {
        switch self {
        case let .apple(x):
            self = .apple(x + 1)
        case let .banana(x, y, z):
            self = .banana(x + 1, y + 1, z + 1)
        }
    }
}

var a = Fruit.banana(100, 200, 300)
a.increment()
```

---

You could also add support for generic operators:

```swift
enum Fruit {
    case apple(Int)
    case banana(Int, Int, Int)

    mutating func operate(_ op: (Int, Int) -> Int,_ num: Int) {
        switch self {
        case let .apple(x):
            self = .apple(op(x, num))
        case let .banana(x, y, z):
            self = .banana(op(x, num), op(y, num), op(z, num))
        }
    }
}

var a = Fruit.banana(100, 200, 300)
a.operate(+, 1) // adds all by 1
a.operate(*, 500) // multiplies all by 500
```

---

You could also add support for an array of generic operators:

```swift
enum Fruit {
    case apple(Int)
    case banana(Int, Int, Int)

    mutating func operate(_ nest: [((Int, Int) -> Int, Int)]) {
        for i in nest {
            switch self {
            case let .apple(x):
                self = .apple(i.0(x, i.1))
            case let .banana(x, y, z):
                self = .banana(i.0(x, i.1), i.0(y, i.1), i.0(z, i.1))
            }
        }
    }
}

var a = Fruit.banana(100, 200, 300)
a.operate([(+, 500), (*, 2)]) // Adds all by 500, then multiply all by 2
```

---

## Here's a nice simplification

If it were up to me, this is what I would do to get rid of repeating `self =`. You can simplify this further if you wish.

```swift
enum FruitList: String { case apple, banana }
struct Fruit {
    static func apple(_ one: Int) -> Fruit {
        return Fruit.init(.apple, [one])
    }
    static func banana(_ one: Int,_ two: Int,_ three: Int) -> Fruit {
        return Fruit.init(.apple, [one, two, three])
    }
    
    var picked: (FruitList, [Int])
    init(_ fruit: FruitList,_ list: [Int]) {
        picked = (fruit, list)
    }
    
    mutating func operate(_ nest: [((Int, Int) -> Int, Int)]) {
        for i in nest {
            for j in 0..<picked.1.count {
                picked.1[j] = i.0(picked.1[j], i.1)
            }
        }
    }
}


var a = Fruit.apple(100)
a.operate([(+, 500), (*, 2)]) // Add all by 500, then multiply all by 2
```

Comment: Thank you! Both the first solution and the second solution are elegant.